# Guava Lists.transform - what if one input is bad?

Tags: java, collections, exception, guava

I am using the [Lists.transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method. In this I have a string input an a CustomObject output. The string input should contain one colon. I am then splitting on this colon and then creating the custom object from the two parts of the string.

So the input is

```
a:b
c:d
e:f
```

and the output is three CustomObject contain `a, b`  `c, d` and `e, f`

My code is something like

```
return new ArrayList(Lists.transform(groups, new Function<String, CustomObject>() {
        @Override
        public CustomObject apply(String input) {
            String[] split = input.split(":");
            String one = split[0];
            String two = split[1];
            return new CustomObject(one, two);
        }
    }));
```

My question is that the list I get sent is coming from the user. If I have a bad input I want to skip that item of the list

So if the input list contains

```
a:b
d
e,f
g:h
```

then I want two CustomObject containing `a:b` and `g:h`

Is this possible in Guava?

If I was doing it the long winded way I would just have a continue in the for loop and log the error.

For example as pseudo-code

```
for loop {
   if no colon present
      continue;
   create CustomObject
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you can just use the old for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach would be more functional, and I'd use [`FluentIterable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html):

```
return FluentIterable.from(groups).transform(new Function<String, CustomObject>() {
        @Override
        public CustomObject apply(String input) {
            String[] split = Iterables.toArray(
               Splitter.on(':').trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(input),
               String.class);
            if(split.length!=2) return null; // bad input data
            String one = split[0];
            String two = split[1];
            return new CustomObject(one, two);
        }
    }).filter(notNull()).toImmutableList();
         //   ^^  -- Predicates.*
```

And I'd convert both the Function and the Splitter to constants.

Comment: Or `Predicates.notNull()` directly.

Comment: @FrankPavageau nice, I'd missed that :-) changed my answer now

Answer (score 13):

If you really do not want to go the "classical" way, you can always use [Iterables.removeIf](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#removeIf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) before you transform.

But the "good old loop" way is probably better for you. Guava developers frown upon abuse of these functional idioms as they [explain here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained):

> Excessive use of Guava's functional programming idioms can lead to verbose, confusing, unreadable, and inefficient code. These are by far the most easily (and most commonly) abused parts of Guava, and when you go to preposterous lengths to make your code "a one-liner," the Guava team weeps.

Comment: +1. actually a more functional style would be to use Iterables.filter to sanitize input and then transform what's left, but I agree on not abusing guava.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your function to return an Optional, and use Optional.presentInstances():

```
    return Optional.presentInstances(Iterables.transform(groups, new Function<String, Optional<CustomObject>>() {
        @Override
        public Optional<CustomObject> apply(String input) {
            if (*/ bad input data */) {
                return Optional.absent();
            }
            // ...
            return Optional.of(new CustomObject("", ""));
        }
    }));
```